# « Néanmoins » et français parlé

Tags: conjonctions, français-relâché

- Néanmoins s'emploie-t-il dans le français parlé relâché ? Ou son usage est-il limité dans le français écrit et plus soutenu ?
- Dans le français parlé relâché, quelles tournures peuvent exprimer l'opposition et la concession ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Non, *néanmoins* ne s'emploie pas vraiment dans le français parlé relâché.
- Oui, son usage est limité au français écrit ou soutenu.
- Voici quelques expressions qui peuvent remplacer *néanmoins* suivant le cas :

> Cependant (soutenu, mais un peu moins que *néanmoins*)
>   Quand même
>   Mais
>   Mais quand même
>   Pourtant
>   N'empêche que (informel)

Comment: Merci encore. Alors néanmoins ne s'emploie pas dans un langage relâché si je comprends bien. L'autre réponse est donc fausse, non ?

Comment: L'autre réponse n'est pas très compréhensible.

Comment: C'est bon. Merci.